# How do boost multipliers work on Aggression cars?

Tags: burnout-paradise

When driving an Aggression car I sometimes notice a 2x or 3x multiplier on the boost gauge. The higher this multiplier the larger the boost meter gets. How do these boost multipliers work on Aggression cars? How do I increase my multiplier?

[image: 3x boost multiplier]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Burnout Wiki](https://burnout.fandom.com/wiki/Aggression_boost#Burnout_Paradise_Boost), you can increase the length of an Aggression car's boost bar by taking down rival drivers. The boost bar can be 1x, 2x, or 3x length depending on how many rivals you've taken down and how many times you've been taken down by rivals.